# when i upload a image if it be big i got this message 403 Forbidden when i want to show it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, image-uploading

my model is this

```
class Image (model.Model):     
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pic_folder/', default='', help_text='')
```

my form is this

```
class Image(form.Form):
      Image = form.ImageField()
```

my view is this

```
def Image(request):
   if request.method=="POST":
      form =Image(request.POST,request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
             cd =form.cleaned_data
             t = Image(Image=cd["Image"])
              t.save()
   else:
       form=Image()
       return render(request,"template.html",{'form':form}
```

template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token%}
   <input type="file" name="Image" >
   <input type="submit" name="" valu="ok">
</form>
```

if the image be small it will be ok 
but if it be large
i got this

[image: 403 Outpub]

Comment: 403 error representing  *permission denied*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

permission denied is raised from nginx, add nginx log error to your question
the nginx didn't allow me to to save more than 2 mb files

Answer (score 1):

Nginx forbid you from uploading file, because your file size is greater than client_max_body_size. Edit your nginx configs, add client_max_body_size. Change it like below:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    //other lines...
}
```

Comment: @rezayousofvand permission denied is raised from nginx, add nginx log error to your question